# How to properly print a double to cout in C++

Tags: c++, printing, double, cout

I've had a look at some questions before posting this and couldn't find what I was looking for, so if it's a duplicate I'm sorry.

I have this code:

```
cout << "The balance at year " << i << " will be " << char(156) << std::setprecision(2)
     << balance << endl;
```

To my knowledge this should print to the console something like:

```
£2.00
£100.46
```

*fyi Above are just examples I know there's nothing to suggest those numbers, but the format should look like that, right?

But here's my output:

```
£1e+002
£1.1e+002
```

Why is it doing this?

It was my understanding that using `setprecision` would show 2 decimal places and nothing more.

Oh and also noticed hardly any questions about printing doubles that said use `setprecision` actually state that this needs including:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Comment: You could save yourself some commentary by simply writing: `double balance = 100.46;` before the `cout` line.  In C++, headers like `<iomanip>` can be included by other standard headers, so the explicit use is often not necessary.  You're assuming an ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15 code set; that is OK in the short term, but it is as well to know that it could cause trouble later.

Comment: thanks for the comment but i simplified by sample code so that i wasnt posting unrelated stuff but no its not as simple as setting the double to equal a number and then just print that.

Comment: my double value im printing out is the result of a calculation so it needs its length fixed on print

Comment: We all know your real code is more complex, but you should aim for an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  You could have: `#include <iostream> using namespace std; int main() { double balance = 100.457213; cout << "The balance at year " << i << " will be " << char(156) << std::setprecision(2) << balance << endl; }` as the complete runnable program, couldn't you?

Comment: @leffler yea I'm sure i could but for something that required this kind of easy answer i really didn't think it was necessary

Comment: i knew it was just some small syntax problem i just didnt know what and seemingly couldnt find a similar question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setprecision` sets the precision, number of digits.

`fixed` sets fixed format.

i bet that'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill give it a try now and then give best answer if its working

Comment: Great thanks, that works ill accept answer now, Any chance of some votes on this question so that others might be drawn here first, a lot of the other answers actually say nothing about this or the include hence why i put "properly" in the title

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::fixed` to set fixed format, rather than scientific notation.

`cout << "The balance at year " << i << " will be " << char(156) << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << balance << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
cout << "The balance at year " << i << " will be " << char(156) << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << balance << endl;
```